# Replacing a sql column value based on a column another table

Tags: mapping, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table1 (col1,col2) and table2(col1,col2) as given below/

[image: table definitions]

Now i need to replace values of col2 of table1 with corresponding value of col1 and col2 from table2. So that the final table should look like this. how can we do this in query??

[image: Final table]

Comment: Those data types aren't the same between instances of table1...

Comment: Do you intend to change the data type of `col2`, or just store data that looks numeric in prose?

Comment: @habo both columns accept text.. i need to store the data..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume table1.col2 and table2.col2 have the same text type(?)

```
update table1 set table1.col2=table2.col2
from table1 
join table2 on (table1.col2=table2.col1)
```