# SQL update column from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, mapping, sql-update

I have a scenario similar to the one in the question here: [Replacing a sql column value based on a column another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248413/replacing-a-sql-column-value-based-on-a-column-another-table)

I have tried this method using the code below:

```
update stager."Supplier" set genid=supplierdim.genid
from stager."Supplier" 
join stager.supplierdim on ("Supplier".company_name=supplierdim.company_name)
```

I am using pgAdmin and I keep getting this error: table name "Supplier" specified more than once.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I need to replace the fields of the table stager."Supplier" with the corresponding fields in stager.supplierdim depending on the company name which is a field in both tables. I am doing this to map the data from one table to another.

Answer (score 1):

Because the question you are referring to is tagged for SQL Server, here is the correct syntax for that database:

```
update s
     set genid = sd.genid
   from stager."Supplier" s join
        stager.supplierdim sd
        on s.company_name = sd.company_name;
```

EDIT:

The syntax in MySQL is:

```
update stager."Supplier" s join
      stager.supplierdim sd
      on s.company_name = sd.company_name;
   set s.genid = sd.genid;
```

EDIT II:

And generic SQL for this:

```
update stager.Supplier
    set genid = (select min(genid)
                 from stager.supplierdim sd
                 where Supplier.company_name = sd.company_name
                );
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The name of the database is Tastrade and stager is one schema in it

Comment: When I use the MySQL version you put with the update stager."Supplier" s join ... I get this error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"